# Multiple External JSON files to be merged

Tags: php, arrays, json, merge

I have around 850 json files and I'd like to merge them in groups of 50.
What would the best method be for this?

array_merge ?

I've seen some examples but none with more than 2 arrays.

```
<?

$array1 = json_decode(file_get_contents('1.json'));
$array2 = json_decode(file_get_contents('2.json'));
$array3 = json_decode(file_get_contents('3.json'));
$array4 = json_decode(file_get_contents('4.json'));
$array5 = json_decode(file_get_contents('5.json'));
$array6 = json_decode(file_get_contents('6.json'));
$array7 = json_decode(file_get_contents('7.json'));
$array8 = json_decode(file_get_contents('8.json'));
$array9 = json_decode(file_get_contents('9.json'));
$array10 = json_decode(file_get_contents('10.json'));
$array11 = json_decode(file_get_contents('11.json'));
$array12 = json_decode(file_get_contents('12.json'));
$array13 = json_decode(file_get_contents('13.json'));
$array14 = json_decode(file_get_contents('14.json'));
$array15 = json_decode(file_get_contents('15.json'));

$result = array_merge($array14, $array15);
var_dump(json_encode($result));

?>
```

Example of 1 of the JSON: http://pastebin.com/QDyGGjQj

Hopeful Outcome (3 out of 50 since 50 is huge example):
http://pastebin.com/fP2MHN2Y

Comment: you can give n number array as parameter in `array_merge` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$dir = = "/files/"; //replace it with yours.
$f = scandir($dir);
foreach($f as $file) {
    $arr[] = json_decode(file_get_contents($file));
}
$chunk = array_chunk($arr,50);
```

After getting all the results in single array you can use `array_chunk`.

Refer this : http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_chunk.asp

Comment: Sadly no result when I attempted to replace the directory path.

Comment: Though it's good to know the array_chunk method exists sadly the chunking method isn't the output I'll be requiring. I need the json example I provided kept in its same format but only appended with the next entry. This would make the Json [{0},{1},{2},{3},{4}] all the way up to 50. Then the array would be under those. This is so I can import 50 tours at once with another tool.

Comment: Can you please post your expected output?

Comment: Here is an example with 3 json files manually merged. http://pastebin.com/fP2MHN2Y  To view I recommend copying into http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ and you'll see how I wish the format to exist.

Comment: Array chunk will work for you.It just gives you an extra parent array.I think this would be fine.You can handle it.

Comment: Thanks for your input, ill look into more as I will have to find a way to either create a new json file with all the new array chunk or a way to print it on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why exactly you'd want to **merge** the arrays instead of making an array of arrays, but I guess something similar to what you're looking for can be achieved by this:

```
$path_to_your_files = '/path/to/your/json/files';
$result = array();
if ($handle = opendir($path_to_your_files)) {
    while (false !== ($filename = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($filename != "." && $filename != "..") {
            $result = $result + json_decode(file_get_contents($path_to_your_files .'/'. $filename));
        }
    }
}
var_dump(json_encode($result));
```

EDIT: added the file system reader.

Comment: Im merging for import use. How would I define the $files to my json files would it be like $files = $i . '.json'; and have a $i within the for each loop?

Comment: Sorry @Sergey-Vidusov it seemed to show string(2) "[]" as a result.

Comment: You sure you're using the correct path to your JSON files?

Comment: I have them in a test folder found in root so I set to /test/

Comment: In this case you may want to have a closer look at that exactly you're passing into `file_get_contents()` and see if it's a valid system filepath. I've also edited my answer above to fix the wrong variable names in the "." and ".." check.